# How can I add opacity transition to this slideshow script? Part 2

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sry to ask again. I have made some progress, but unfortunately I still can't get it done, and I'm getting a bit desperate.

The question I asked yesterday can be found here: [How can I add opacity transition to this script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548746/how-can-i-add-opacity-transition-to-this-script)

As Anthony suggested I'm trying to give the visible img of "mySlides" an extra class called .visible and remove it when the next img is called.

So after some research I managed to give it the new class with: x[slideIndex-1].classList.add("visible")

but the transition still won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i,
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"),
    dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");

  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
    x[i].classList.remove("visible");
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }

  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  x[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("visible")
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-white";
}
```

```css
img.mySlides {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

img.mySlides.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <div id="slider-wrapper">
    <img id="zupfinstrumente" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos" src="img1.jpg" alt="xy">
    <img id="ueber-mich" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos" src="img2.jpg" alt="xy">
    <img id="streichinstrumente" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos" src="img3.jpg" alt="xy"></div>
  <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white centerscreen badgepos">
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
  <container id="buttons" class="centerscreen">
    <div id="navarrow-left" class="w3-left w3-hover-text-black btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div id="navarrow-right" class="w3-right w3-hover-text-black btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
  </container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custumized css annimation then use this last on your `img` wo when the image shown the annimation will trigger ,

the annimation css code :

```
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

See below snippet :

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
 showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
 var i,
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"),
  dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
 
 if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1
 } 
 
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length
 }
 
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
 }
  
 x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}


/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .1} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .1} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <div id="slider-wrapper">
        <img id="zupfinstrumente" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" alt="xy">
        <img id="ueber-mich" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" alt="xy">
        <img id="streichinstrumente" class="centerscreen mySlides slidepos fade" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" alt="xy"></div>
    <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white centerscreen badgepos">
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    </div>
    <container id="buttons" class="centerscreen">
        <div id="navarrow-left" class="w3-left w3-hover-text-black btn" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
        <div id="navarrow-right" class="w3-right w3-hover-text-black btn" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    </container>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! This works great! Thank you soo much! I really appreciate it. No way I would have come up with that solution. I wonder if I could make a fade out as well with that solution.. wasn't able to do that yet.